# How to combine imshow() and moveWindow() in openCV with python?

Tags: python, opencv, imshow

I'm updating the cv2.imshow() command in a endless Loop and I want to manipulate the window position because the window is always on the top of my display and a small part is invisable.

The cv2.moveWindow() command is a nice solution for my task but is there an other way to set the window position only once and not to repeat the command in every Iteration?

I want to update the window every 500 ms. Is there a better way to display the image-stream with fixed window position?

```
while true:
   (...)
   img = cv2.imread('test.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
   cv2.imshow('image',img)  
   cv2.moveWindow('image',200,200)
   (...)
```

Comment: I have ever done the same. I used moveWindow function once before the while loop. If at the beginning you do not have an original image to show you can use a whole black image as default with the same size you are going to use in the loop. (But I was using C++/OpenCV. I don't know if Python works similar)

Comment: Thanks, Summer Fang ! It's working fine in Python, too. See my code below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Summer Fang's comment, I want to show the way how moving the window outside of the loop works for me:

```
test_img = np.zeros(shape=(height,width,3)).astype('uint8')
cv2.imshow('image',test_img)
cv2.moveWindow('image',200,200)
cv2.waitKey(1) 

while true:
   (...)
   img = cv2.imread('test.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
   cv2.imshow('image',img)  
   (...)
```

Comment: Yes good idea. Instead of creating the emtpy image you could also simply do `cv2.imshow('image',cap.read()[1])` on line 2