# How can I disable OpenCV writing image windows position and size to Windows Registry in Python?

Tags: python, windows, opencv, user-interface, registry

Every time I show an image with OpenCV (cv2) and use an image window label with `cv2.imshow(label, image)`, OpenCV creates or updates keys with that window label and the image position and size as values in Windows Registry. The key **is HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\OpenCV\HighGUI\Windows**. (See screenshot below.)

Is there a way to stop OpenCV from doing this?

(My opencv-python version is 4.9.0.80.)

[image]

---

(4 days later)
Note: I was asked (by a moderator?) to check if the question **"How to combine imshow() and moveWindow() in openCV with python?"** could solve my problem. Well, it is quite obvious that the suggested question is **totally** irrelevant with mine. (Moving a window image does not solve the problem of **window names** written in Windows registry.)

Comment: you can set the window position from your program (`cv::moveWindow()`). or you can use a GUI library to do exactly what you need because OpenCV's GUI facilities are a convenience, not a library.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine imshow() and moveWindow() in openCV with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46804380/how-to-combine-imshow-and-movewindow-in-opencv-with-python)

Comment: I'm sorry @Christoph Rackwitz for not replying you, earlier. I have not been notified about your comment. As for the suggested question, I just edited my question regarding it,  in which I say that (your) suggested question is totally irrelevant with mine. **I just don't want OpenCV to write useless data about dozens of different window names.**  Simple as that. Besides, positioning image windows does not solve the problem. The problem has to to with the **window names** one is using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://forum.opencv.org/t/how-can-i-disable-opencv-writing-image-windows-position-and-size-to-windows-registry/16624/2

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz, I have two questions regarding your suggested solution at forum.opencv.org. Waiting for a reply ...

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. `window_w32.cpp` always saves window positions to registry.

You'd need to change OpenCV source to add this feature. And you'd need to think about how to convey this bit of information, either before you create any windows or when you create each window.

Comment: I see. Do you by any chance know in what file of the package can one change that?

Comment: I guess you mean 'window_w32.cpp' right? Since it is a C++ and I don't work with C++, I just disregarded it. The question says **in Python** and there's also a **python**  tag.  So I can't upvote your answer and much less consider it as an accepted one. But I can thank you, anyway. 

Comment: @Apostolos You may not like the reality, but this is the correct answer. You have 4 options: 1) Patch it yourself in the C++ implementation 2) Make feature request in the OpenCV GitHub repository (good luck with this attitude, tho) 3) Pay someone to do it for you 4) Use a different UI toolkit to display the images, that you will have full control over. | P.S.: I too will remember.

Comment: Thank you all for your patience. I too will remember. 